# Sets being subsets of each other

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Can a set $A$ be a subset of a set $B$ and $B$ be a subset of $A$? I know they would just be equal, but are you able to classify them as being subsets of each other?

Comment: I believe this is the definition of equality between two sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of a set $A$ being a subset of a set $B$ means that for each $x \in A$, it must be true that $x \in B$ (that is, every element found in $A$ is found in $B$).

Yes, you can definitely classify two sets as being subsets of each other.  But as you correctly noted, this *only* happens when the two sets are equal to begin with.